# What can be a replacement for javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, netbeans

I'm quite new to file uploading and I'm having a hard time doing a file upload in my web project because this jar file cannot be loaded and whenever I upload a file, I always get this error:

SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet FileUploadServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.Part

Is it because the javax.servlet-api jar file cannot be loaded? Does it not work with Tomcat 6?

All answers will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javax.servlet.http.Part was introduced in Servlet 3.0. Tomcat 6 implements Servlet 2.5

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/

So you'd best upgrade to Tomcat 7 or 8 if possible.